# JavaScript Regex with semi-colon and whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex

This seems a bit hairy at first blush, so I hope someone can give this a once over.

The intention is to split the string into an array of substrings, the characters to split before or after are retained as part of the substring components (i.e. nothing is lost as it would be in a typical split).  The splits should occur right after chars defined in 'endsWith' and right before chars defined in 'startsWith'.

Originally I wrote it with the 'endsWith' functionality, and it worked fine (as demonstrated further in the post), but when I added the 'startsWith' feature things started to get a bit hinky.

```
var input = "foo bar;baz#qux>quux,rawr";

var startsWith = ['#', ','];
var endsWith = [';', '\\s', '>'];

var re = new RegExp("(?=[" + startsWith.join('') + "])(.*?[" + endsWith.join('') + "]+)", "g");
console.log(re); //=> /(?=[#,])(.*?[;\s>]+)/g

var result = input.split(re).filter(Boolean);
console.log(result);
```

Result: [ 'foo bar;baz', '#qux>', 'quux,rawr' ]

Expected: [ 'foo ', 'bar;', 'baz', '#qux>', 'quux', ',rawr' ]

The problem is that it's not splitting after whitespace or semi-colons, curiously though it is splitting after the greater-than symbol.

(After adding a second char to startsWith it is clear that it is not splitting on the common - no matter the order of '#' and ',' in the regex)

Another interesting thing is that removing the 'startsWith' stuff and just making it:

```
    var re = new RegExp("(.*?[" + endsWith.join('') + "]+)", "g");
    console.log(re); //=> /(.*?[;\s>]+)/g
```

The semi-colons and whitespaces now work: [ 'foo ', 'bar;', 'baz#qux>', 'quux,rawr' ]

But I also want the startsWith functionality (having '#qux' and ',rawr' separated), and I don't understand why I'm seeing that issue when that's added back in.

Comment: Could you try to explain your need in plain English? From what I understand, you want to extract strings that start with any of the `startsWith` array and end with any of the `endsWith` array, right?

Comment: What good is the "startsWith" if it does not yield expected results? You ask the regex to start matching from `#` then, and it is exactly what the regex engine is doing when you use `(?=#)`. Remove it if it is not required. If it is required, the first results are expected.

Comment: I've added an english explanation of my intentions sp00m, thanks :)

Comment: I don't understand your comment Wiktor Stribiżew.  The startsWith functionality works, and is required, however adding it causes an issue with the endsWith functionality.

Comment: Try `var re = new RegExp("(" + startsWith.join('') + "?[^" + endsWith.join('') + startsWith.join('')  +  "]*[" + endsWith.join('') + "])");`. The pattern will look like `/(#?[^;\s>#]*[;\s>])/`. That is: make the start pattern optional (1 or 0), then `.*?` should exclude both start and end patterns, and then comes the end pattern as you have.

Comment: Ah, forgot to put the start patterns into a char class. See https://jsfiddle.net/r4fw0bwb/1/

Comment: I've clarified the question again with the addition of a 2nd char in startsWith

Comment: For the down-voters and close-voters, what this allows me to do is create a more efficient 'longest common string' algorithm for deduplication of source code, which typically is delimited by some set of symbols which either denote the start or end of a fragment of code.  If I said I wanted to parse <style>span { color: red; }</style> I'd have the DOM Parser people breathing down my neck, so that's why you get a slightly more obscure example!  Thank you all who gave it a crack :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now check it

```js
var input = "abc&foo bar;baz#qux>quux,awrr";
    var re = /([#,]?[^#;>\s,]*[\;\s\>]?){1}/g
    console.log(re); 

    var result = input.split(re).filter(Boolean);
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: If I put any symbol into the text like & for example, it will split on the &, and that is not one of the valid split characters.

Comment: Getting closer I modified it a bit and this works so far: var re = /([#,]?[^#,;>\s]*[;\s\>]?){1}/g

Comment: again changed for detecting comma(,) @braks

Comment: No need to escape the semi-colon.  But based on your answer I devised this solution - so thank you very much sir! https://jsfiddle.net/7gu9a8or/

Comment: no mention. Sharing knowledge is a good way for improve ourself. Thank you very much for creating such a scenario for me @braks

Answer (score 0):

Define your `re` object:

```
var re = new RegExp("([" + startsWith.join('') + "]+.*?[" + endsWith.join('') + 
         "]+)|[" + endsWith.join('') + "]+");
//=> /(#.*?[;\s>])|[;\s>]+/
```

1. It uses a captured group between `#` to one of the ending characters so that `split` returns same captured text in result
2. It uses alternation to allow for splitting on one of the given characters defined by `endsWith` array.

Then use it as:

```
var result = input.split(re).filter(Boolean);
//=> ["foo", "bar", "baz", "#qux>", "quux"]
```

Comment: Seemed promising, but as soon as I test a variation on the inputs it fails.  var input = "foo bar;baz#qux>quux,rawr";
var startsWith = ['#', ','];

Comment: Try my updated regex in answer now. For your given input it produces: `["foo", "bar", "baz", "#qux>", "quux,rawr"]`

Answer (score 0):

I thik this should work:

```js
const splitChars = [' ', ';', '#', '>']
const regex = new RegExp(`(.*?(?:${splitChars.join('|')}))`)
let str = "foo bar;baz#qux>quux"

const array = str.split(regex).filter(x => x != "")
console.log(array)
```

Comment: This produces an incorrect result: [ 'foo ',  'bar;',  'baz#',  'qux>',  'quux' ] as opposed to  [ 'foo ', 'bar;', 'baz', '#qux>', 'quux' ] - notice the # symbol.